# Getting error while runing the react-native run-android

Tags: android, linux, react-native

While running the ***react-native run-android***  cmd getting the failed build.

```
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

**Here Have some environment Details react-native info**

```
System:
    OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-10100 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    Memory: 200.08 MB / 7.64 GB
    Shell: 4.4.20 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.22.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.5/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.5 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 7.22.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.5/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_292 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.17 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Android/Sdk
```

Solved the problem for me on Linux. Try replacing with your own Android SDK path.